# Messages do not get queued if the queue is declared with arguments

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I used the following code to store a message in a queue:

```
channel.queueDeclare(Queuename, durable, false, false, null);
```

Its working. But if I use `args` instead of `null`, the message does not reach the Queue:

```
channel.queueDeclare(Queuename, durable, false, false, args);
```

Why aren't messages reaching the queue with the above queue declaration?

Queue name in code:

```
private final static String idnQueue = "idnQueue";
```

Comment: Doesn't the documentation specify the difference?

Comment: If you have a question about RabbitMQ, then tagging it as [tag:rabbitmq] might get you more views.

Comment: Can you include the code where you create 'Queuename' and 'args'?  I'm assuming your channel is of type 'com.rabbitmq.client.Channel'?  What version of rabbitmq-java-client are you using?

Comment: Question is bit unclear.can you please update this? BTW are you getting IOException while running queueDeclare()? Have you done the binding right?